# Windows 8 Website

Tags: html, css, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am making a new website in this website there will be Windows 8 Version and A classic Version I want To know How to code this Win8 Version ?

```
<style>
    body{background:url('win8.gif');}
     */other Styles \*
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You should See [this](http://metroui.org.ua/) Website